# Identify non self-intersecting polygons

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon

I have a shiny app where the user can define a polygon, but I want to throw a warning if the polygon self-intersects.

I made the MWE below.

```
polygon=data.frame(x_coord=c(1,2.5,7.5,6.75,4), y_coord=c(5,7,6.5,0.75,0.25))
polygon=data.frame(x_coord=c(1.5,2.5,7.5,5.5,4.5), y_coord=c(3,7,6.5,3,7.5))
not_intersect <- TRUE #how to define if the polygon self-intersects?
if (not_intersect==TRUE){
  P <- ggplot2::ggplot(polygon, ggplot2::aes(x=x_coord, y=y_coord)) +
       ggplot2::geom_polygon(fill="#99CCFF", color="red", alpha=0.25, linewidth=1, linetype=2) +
       ggplot2::geom_point(color="red", size=1.5) +
       ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 10), breaks = seq(0,10)) +
       ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10), breaks = seq(0,10)) +
       ggplot2::theme_light()
  grDevices::pdf(file="test.pdf", height=6, width=6)
  print(P)
  grDevices::dev.off()
}
```

Essentially, if the polygon is like the first one, I want to plot it:

[image: test1]

But if it is like the second one, I don't want to plot it:

[image: test2]

Any idea on how to identify these 2 types of polygons?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *valid* polygon is [defined](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Geospatial/ST_IsValid.htm#:%7E:text=A%20polygon%20or%20multipolygon%20is,polygon%20except%20at%20a%20vertex.) by the [Open Geospatial Consortium](https://www.ogc.org/) as:

1. The polygon is closed; its start point is the same as its end point.
2. Its boundary is a set of linestrings.
3. The boundary does not touch or cross itself.
4. Any polygons in the interior do not touch the boundary of the exterior polygon except at a vertex.

We can use [`sf::st_is_valid()`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/valid.html) to check for validity. We can set the `reason = TRUE` parameter to check in particular for self-intersection (the third condition):

```r
# The same polygons as in your question
polygon1 <- data.frame(x_coord = c(1, 2.5, 7.5, 6.75, 4), y_coord = c(5, 7, 6.5, 0.75, 0.25))
polygon2 <- data.frame(x_coord = c(1.5, 2.5, 7.5, 5.5, 4.5), y_coord = c(3, 7, 6.5, 3, 7.5))

library(sf)

has_self_intersection  <- function(p) {
     p_is_valid <- list(as.matrix(p)) |>
        st_multilinestring() |>
        st_cast("POLYGON") |>
        st_is_valid(reason = TRUE)
    any(startsWith(p_is_valid, "Self-intersection"))
}

has_self_intersection(polygon1) # FALSE
has_self_intersection(polygon2) # TRUE
```

Note: I have called it `has_self_intersection()` rather than `not_intersects` because of the advice in [How to name functions that return booleans](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/445555/how-to-name-functions-that-return-booleans):

> Steve McDonnel's popular Code Complete suggests the list that you have "is", "has", "should", or "can", but for variable names.

Your code will then be:

```r
if (!has_self_intersection(polygon)){
    # draw the plot
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I agree with not including a negation in the function, I just named `self_intersects`